# Union especial de dataframes pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

muy buenas necesitaria ayuda para hacer algo asi, he intentado varias cosas sin resultado:

```
-df1

|id_cliente  |  nombre    |  apellido  |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|01          |    juan    |   fernandez|

-df2

|id_cliente  |  contacto    |   telefono1  |  telefono2   |  email |
| ---------- | ----------   | ----------   |----------    | -------|
|01          |administracion|  11111111    | 222222       | prueba@prueba.es
|01          |  secretario  |  5555555     |  nan         |  nan
```

resultado que busco:

```
df3

id_cliente  | nombre | apellido |  contacto  |  telefono1  |  telefono2   |  email           |contacto      |  telefono1   | telefono2    | email  
01          |juan    |fernandez | admon      | 11111111    |222222        | prueba@prueba.es |  secretario  |  5555555     |  nan         |  nan |
```

*Es decir es una especie de agrupacion o union de los df por el id_cliente pero que la unión sea en la misma fila.*

Comment: Hay un problema con lo que buscas. Cada cliente puede tener distinto número de entradas en `df`2`, por ejemplo, tienes a este cliente 01 que en `df2` tiene dos entradas, y por tanto genera 8 columnas extra en df3 (4 por cada entrada). Pero puedes tener otros clientes con solo una entrada (que generarían 4 columnas) y otros con N entradas (que generarían N*4 columnas). El df3 resultante por tanto tendría que tener tantas columnas como el máximo (N*4), y tener montones de NaN en los clientes que tengan menos entradas. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: tiene máximo 3 entradas en df2, es decir, generaría 12 columnas máximo. Lo de el tema de los NaN no importa, es decir si hay clientes con 2 entradas y genera 8 columnas, las otras 4 quedarían a NaN. Gracias!

Comment: @abulafia He intentado hacer una función que me devuelva df3, cuyas columnas son todas las de df1 y después para las columnas nuevas de df2 he intentado hacer algo así: t1 = for tfno1 in set(df2.telefono1.dropna())... de momento nada...eres mi esperanza para darme ideas :) Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente lo he conseguido:

TRATAMIENTO AL DF2

1.- Creo un campo unico

> df2['unicos']=df2['contacto'].astype(str)+ "," +
> df2['telefono_1'].astype(str)+ "," + df2['telefono_2'].astype(str)+
> "," + df2['email_1'].astype(str)

2.- Creo una funcion para la agrupacion:

> def unicos(df):
>
> ```
> unicos= "|".join(f"{unicos}" for unicos in set(df.unicos))
> return pd.DataFrame({"Unicos":[unicos]})
> ```

3.-Agrupo por id cliente:

> df3=df2.groupby(["id_cliente"]).apply(unicos).droplevel(-1).reset_index() df4=df3.reset_index()

4.- Divido en columnas por el divisor creado en la funcion:

#Dividimos la columna de unicos(Sabiendo que tengo 3 conjunto de datos)

> df4['unicos1']=df4['Unicos'].str.split('|').str[0] df4['unicos2'] =
> df4['Unicos'].str.split('|').str[1] df4['unicos3'] =
> df4['Unicos'].str.split('|').str[2] df4=df4.drop(['Unicos'], axis=1)

5.- Divido las columnas unico1,unico2 y unico3 con split por , ya que los concatene así:

> df4['contacto1']=df4['unicos1'].str.split(',').str[0] df4['telefono1']
> = df4['unicos1'].str.split(',').str[1] df4['telefono2'] = df4['unicos1'].str.split(',').str[2] df4['email1'] =
> df4['unicos1'].str.split(',').str[3]

.....asi con las 3 columnas unicos creadas...

6.- Elimino las columnas unico

> df4=df4.drop(['unicos1'], axis=1) df4=df4.drop(['unicos2'], axis=1)
> df4=df4.drop(['unicos3'], axis=1)

7.- Ultimo paso hago merge al df primero y creo un dataframe nuevo con todas las columnas del df y el df2 con id_cliente unico y los contactos en una misma fila...